# A Warning from Jesus

Tags: exegesis, gospel-of-matthew, non-christians

If Jesus really loves everyone, why does Jesus show no mercy on the non believers?

Matthew 7:21-23:

```
Not everyone who calls me their Lord will get into the kingdom of heaven.  
Only the ones who obey my Father in heaven will get in.
On the day of judgment many will call me their Lord.
They will say, "We preached in your name, and in your name we force out demons and
worked many miracles."  But I will tell them, "I will have nothing to do with you!
Get out of my sight, you evil people!"
```

Since this question is on hold due to opinion base, I'll attempt to form it more not opinion base.  Matthew 7:21-23 has always disturbed me.  Why does this passage warn and state the response from Jesus to the individuals who confront him with mercy?  The quotes could be left out and the passage could just be:

```
Not everyone who calls me their Lord will get into the kingdom of heaven.
Only the ones who obey my Father in heaven will get in.
On the day of judgment many will call me their Lord.
```

Is this due to translation from the old testament to the new testament?

Comment: Who says that he shows no mercy? He does not smite them instantly after their first sin...

Comment: This verse isn't about non-believers.  It's about believers who commit mortal sins.

Comment: Welcome to the site. We are glad you decided to participate. This question is off-topic and does not fit into one of the [Types of questions that are within community guidelines](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/3409) If possible, [edit] this question so that it better fits into one of those question types.

Comment: Some do believe that *everyone* will be saved. It is called universalism. Related: [What is the Biblical basis for Universal salvation?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/525) | [How do opponents of Decision Theology distinguish themselves from Universal Salvation?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/17550) | [How does Calvinism explain how an omniscient, omnipotent, and omnibenevolent creator could NOT have a plan for universal salvation?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/24178) | [Universalism in the Orthodox Church?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/12108)

Comment: and [Does the Catholic Church oppose universalism?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/10168)

Comment: If you'd like to read my answer to your question, feel free to let me know, and I'll email it to you. My email address in drlarter@yahoo.com. Don

Comment: I don't quite understand the question now. As dark wanderer said, most Christians believe that the verse refers to people who do Christian things, but are not truly Christian in their hearts. It really does sound like you are asking about universalism, of which I've linked five questions above. Perhaps check those out. The wikipedia article on it is okay too for general reference.

Comment: I think the problem is that different theologies result in different interpretations of the passage. Perhaps you should rephrase your question as "How is this passage interpreted by different groups?".

Comment: There are two separate issues in this question: 1. Why doesn't Jesus show mercy to unbelievers? 2. What is the meaning of Matthew 7:21-23? Choose one here, and if you want answer to the other too, make another question on it. Then maybe I can help you rephrasing your question to be less opinion-based.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best explanation I heard on this passage goes like this : "Depart from me all those who professed to be my followers, yet lived your lives as if I had never given you commands to live by". In other words, all those who never tried to be holy like Jesus.  And, by the way, ALL sins are mortal unless they are forgiven by Jesus. And He can forgive EVERY sin.

Comment: Juhani, your answer is better than mine :)

Comment: Welcome to the site. We're glad you're here. Generally, the community likes a bit more out of the answers. You can always [edit] this to make it better. I hope to see you post again soon.

Answer (score 2):

An excellent few verses from the Book of Mormon

> 25 What, do ye suppose that mercy can rob justice? I say unto you, Nay; not one whit. If so, God would cease to be God.
>   26 And thus God bringeth about his great and eternal purposes, which were prepared from the foundation of the world. And thus cometh about the salvation and the redemption of men, and also their destruction and misery.
>   27 Therefore, O my son, whosoever will come may come and partake of the waters of life freely; and whosoever will not come the same is not compelled to come; but in the last day it shall be restored unto him according to his deeds.
>   28 If he has desired to do evil, and has not repented in his days, behold, evil shall be done unto him, according to the restoration of God.
>   29 And now, my son, I desire that ye should let these things trouble you no more, and only let your sins trouble you, with that trouble which shall bring you down unto repentance.

Jesus has already shown us His mercy by opening for us a way to escape the just recompense of our sins.  The verses you cite in Matthew 7 speak of the end results for those who refused that mercy, as it was predicated upon obedience to the principles and ordinances of Christ's gospel.

Answer (score 2):

I think KJV has a more accurate (and clearer) translation of this.

> 21 ¶ Not every one that saith unto me, Lord, Lord,
>   shall enter into the kingdom of heaven; but he that
>   doeth the will of my Father which is in heaven.
>   22 Many will say to me in that day, Lord, Lord, have
>   we not prophesied in thy name? and in thy name
>   have cast out devils? and in thy name done many
>   wonderful works?
>   23 And then will I profess unto them, I never knew
>   you: depart from me, ye that work iniquity.

The key here is the will of the Father. It is illustrated in John 6:39-40.

> 39 And **this is the Father’s will which hath sent me**,
>   that of all which he hath given me I should lose
>   nothing, but should raise it up again at the last day.
>   40 And **this is the will of him that sent me, that every
>   one which seeth the Son, and believeth on him, may
>   have everlasting life**: and I will raise him up at the
>   last day.

So Father's will is that you believe in his only begotten Son, that you might have everlasting life, so your question is correct.

The reason Jesus can't show mercy to unbelievers is that he is a just God. All we have sinned and come short of the glory of God (Romans 3:23), and we deserve the everlasting punishment, which is the lake of fire prepared for the devil and his angels. It isn't meant for men, and God doesn't want anyone to end up in there. Because we can't possibly expiate our sins, God, being in Christ, reconciled the world unto himself, not imputing their trespasses unto them; and hath committed unto us the word of reconciliation (2 Cor 5:19). And this isn't just mercy, this is grace, because not only we don't get what we deserve, but we get what we don't deserve, even eternal life.

Comment: Welcome to the site. We are glad you're here. Please take the [tour] and glance through the [help] if you have not already. I hope to see you post again soon.